# mod_cluster https redirect is not working when an application server is registered

Tags: jboss, load-balancing, apache, httpd.conf

I am using mod_cluster 1.2 as a load balancer and JBoss AS7 as nodes. I have configured AJP connector in JBoss and mod_cluster is connected with JBoss nodes.

I want to achieve the following,
Client <--HTTPS--> Balancer <--AJP--> JBoss

Here is my mod_cluster configuration,

```
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_cluster_module modules/mod_proxy_cluster.so
LoadModule manager_module modules/mod_manager.so
LoadModule slotmem_module modules/mod_slotmem.so
LoadModule advertise_module modules/mod_advertise.so

LogLevel debug

ServerName localhost

<IfModule manager_module>
  Listen 127.0.0.1:6666
  ManagerBalancerName mycluster
  <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:6666>

    <Location />
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
    </Location>

     <Location /mcm>
       SetHandler mod_cluster-manager
       Order deny,allow
       Deny from all
       Allow from 127.0.0
    </Location>

    KeepAliveTimeout 300
    MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
    AdvertiseFrequency 5
    EnableMCPMReceive

  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
 RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}  [R,L]
</VirtualHost>

  Listen 443
  <VirtualHost *:443>
    <Location />
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
    </Location>

    SSLEngine  On
    SSLCACertificateFile  C:/work/certs/gs/root.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile  C:/work/certs/gs/inter.pem
    SSLCertificateFile  C:/work/certs/gs/kc.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile  C:/work/certs/gs/key.key

  </VirtualHost>
```

When JBoss is not registered with mod_cluster, and I try `http://localhost` it is redirected to `https://localhost`. But when a JBoss node is registered the HTTPS redirection is not working. It is opening the page in HTTP mode only. Please help me to resolve this.

***EDIT:***

As per karm's suggestion I have configured the Worker<--HTTPS-->Balancer configuration. But still same effect. When Jboss is registered with m_c, the redirection is not working.

Here is my m_c configuration,

```
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so


LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_cluster_module modules/mod_proxy_cluster.so
LoadModule manager_module modules/mod_manager.so
LoadModule slotmem_module modules/mod_slotmem.so
LoadModule advertise_module modules/mod_advertise.so


ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
LogLevel debug


ServerName localhost


Listen 8800
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8800>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond  %{SERVER_PORT} !^8888$
 RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}:8888%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>


<IfModule manager_module>
  Listen 8888
  ManagerBalancerName qacluster
  <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8888>
    <Directory />
      Order deny,allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from all
    </Directory>


    KeepAliveTimeout 300
    MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
    AdvertiseFrequency 5
    EnableMCPMReceive


    #ServerAdvertise on
    #AdvertiseGroup 224.0.1.105:6666


    <Location /mcm>
      SetHandler mod_cluster-manager
      Order deny,allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from all
   </Location>


    SSLEngine  On
    SSLCACertificateFile  C:/work/certs/gs/gs_root.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile  C:/work/certs/gs/gs_inter.pem
    SSLCertificateFile  C:/work/certs/gs/kc.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile  C:/work/certs/gs/kc.key


  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

JBoss configuration,

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:modcluster:1.0">
        <mod-cluster-config proxy-list="127.0.0.1:8888" advertise="false" excluded-contexts="admin-console,invoker,jbossws,jmx-console,juddi,web-console">
            <ssl key-alias="1" password="changeit" certificate-key-file="C:\Users\jai\.keystore" ca-certificate-file="C:\work\certs\gs\ca.jks"/>
        </mod-cluster-config>
    </subsystem>
```

After JBoss is registered with m_c the link `http://localhost:8800/mcm` itself not working.

Here is the debug logs from m_c,

```
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:13 2012] [info] Init: Seeding PRNG with 0 bytes of entropy
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:13 2012] [info] Loading certificate & private key of SSL-aware server
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:13 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_pphrase.c(470): unencrypted RSA private key - pass phrase not required
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:13 2012] [info] Init: Generating temporary RSA private keys (512/1024 bits)
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:13 2012] [info] Init: Generating temporary DH parameters (512/1024 bits)
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:13 2012] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:13 2012] [info] Init: Initializing (virtual) servers for SSL
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:13 2012] [info] Configuring server for SSL protocol
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:13 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(465): Creating new SSL context (protocols: SSLv2, SSLv3, TLSv1)
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:13 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(601): Configuring client authentication
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:13 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(748): Configuring server certificate chain (1 CA certificate)
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:13 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(420): Configuring TLS extension handling
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:13 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(795): Configuring RSA server certificate
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:13 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(834): Configuring RSA server private key
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:13 2012] [info] mod_ssl/2.2.21 compiled against Server: Apache/2.2.21, Library: OpenSSL/0.9.8r
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:13 2012] [info] Init: Seeding PRNG with 0 bytes of entropy
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:14 2012] [info] Loading certificate & private key of SSL-aware server
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:14 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_pphrase.c(470): unencrypted RSA private key - pass phrase not required
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:14 2012] [info] Init: Generating temporary RSA private keys (512/1024 bits)
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:14 2012] [info] Init: Generating temporary DH parameters (512/1024 bits)
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:14 2012] [info] Init: Initializing (virtual) servers for SSL
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:14 2012] [info] Configuring server for SSL protocol
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:14 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(465): Creating new SSL context (protocols: SSLv2, SSLv3, TLSv1)
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:14 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(601): Configuring client authentication
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:14 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(748): Configuring server certificate chain (1 CA certificate)
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:14 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(420): Configuring TLS extension handling
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:14 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(795): Configuring RSA server certificate
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:14 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(834): Configuring RSA server private key
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:14 2012] [info] mod_ssl/2.2.21 compiled against Server: Apache/2.2.21, Library: OpenSSL/0.9.8r
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:14 2012] [notice] Advertise initialized for process 6148
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:14 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0g mod_cluster/1.2.0.Final configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:14 2012] [notice] Server built: Feb  9 2012 22:24:33
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:14 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 5660
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:14 2012] [debug] mpm_winnt.c(477): Parent: Sent the scoreboard to the child
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:14 2012] [info] Init: Seeding PRNG with 0 bytes of entropy
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:14 2012] [info] Loading certificate & private key of SSL-aware server
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:14 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_pphrase.c(470): unencrypted RSA private key - pass phrase not required
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:14 2012] [info] Init: Generating temporary RSA private keys (512/1024 bits)
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:14 2012] [info] Init: Generating temporary DH parameters (512/1024 bits)
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:14 2012] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:14 2012] [info] Init: Initializing (virtual) servers for SSL
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:14 2012] [info] Configuring server for SSL protocol
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:14 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(465): Creating new SSL context (protocols: SSLv2, SSLv3, TLSv1)
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:14 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(601): Configuring client authentication
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:14 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(748): Configuring server certificate chain (1 CA certificate)
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:14 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(420): Configuring TLS extension handling
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:14 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(795): Configuring RSA server certificate
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:14 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(834): Configuring RSA server private key
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:14 2012] [info] mod_ssl/2.2.21 compiled against Server: Apache/2.2.21, Library: OpenSSL/0.9.8r
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:15 2012] [info] Init: Seeding PRNG with 0 bytes of entropy
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:15 2012] [info] Loading certificate & private key of SSL-aware server
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:15 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_pphrase.c(470): unencrypted RSA private key - pass phrase not required
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:15 2012] [info] Init: Generating temporary RSA private keys (512/1024 bits)
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:15 2012] [info] Init: Generating temporary DH parameters (512/1024 bits)
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:15 2012] [info] Init: Initializing (virtual) servers for SSL
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:15 2012] [info] Configuring server for SSL protocol
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:15 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(465): Creating new SSL context (protocols: SSLv2, SSLv3, TLSv1)
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:15 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(601): Configuring client authentication
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:15 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(748): Configuring server certificate chain (1 CA certificate)
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:15 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(420): Configuring TLS extension handling
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:15 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(795): Configuring RSA server certificate
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:15 2012] [debug] ssl_engine_init.c(834): Configuring RSA server private key
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:15 2012] [info] mod_ssl/2.2.21 compiled against Server: Apache/2.2.21, Library: OpenSSL/0.9.8r
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:15 2012] [debug] mod_advertise.c(577): [5660 - 6148] in child post config hook
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:15 2012] [notice] Child 5660: Child process is running
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:15 2012] [debug] mpm_winnt.c(398): Child 5660: Retrieved our scoreboard from the parent.
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:15 2012] [info] Parent: Duplicating socket 128 and sending it to child process 5660
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:15 2012] [info] Parent: Duplicating socket 124 and sending it to child process 5660
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:15 2012] [debug] mpm_winnt.c(595): Parent: Sent 2 listeners to child 5660
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:15 2012] [debug] mpm_winnt.c(554): Child 5660: retrieved 2 listeners from parent
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:15 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1818): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 5660 for worker proxy:reverse
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:15 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1914): proxy: initialized worker 0 in child 5660 for (*) min=0 max=64 smax=64
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:15 2012] [notice] Child 5660: Acquired the start mutex.
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:15 2012] [notice] Child 5660: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:15 2012] [notice] Child 5660: Starting thread to listen on port 8888.
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:15 2012] [notice] Child 5660: Starting thread to listen on port 8800.
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:16 2012] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(678): update_workers_node starting
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:16 2012] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(693): update_workers_node done
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:16 2012] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(678): update_workers_node starting
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:16 2012] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(693): update_workers_node done
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:16 2012] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(678): update_workers_node starting
[Tue Nov 20 11:43:16 2012] [debug] mod_proxy_cluster.c(693): update_workers_node done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with mod_cluster 1.2.0. I took latest mod_cluster code and compiled and used. The HTTPS redirection worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, this is all a very strange configuration... SSLProxyVerify require? Mod_cluster actually is a MITM attack :-) Furthermore, SSL must be On for Mod_cluster itself. Take a look:

1) Worker nodes can register with the balancer.

2) Connection is secured: client<--SSL-->balancer<--SSL-->workers, though, worker must trust the balancer...

3) Accessing e.g.

```
http://localhost:8800/mcm
```

is redirected to the secured

```
https://localhost:8888/mcm
```

I guess that is what you want?

**HTTPD**

```
# mod_proxy_balancer should be disabled when mod_cluster is used
LoadModule proxy_cluster_module modules/mod_proxy_cluster.so
LoadModule slotmem_module modules/mod_slotmem.so
LoadModule manager_module modules/mod_manager.so
LoadModule advertise_module modules/mod_advertise.so

MemManagerFile /home/karm/httpd/logs

Listen 8800
<VirtualHost localhost:8800>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond  %{SERVER_PORT} !^8888$
 RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}:8888%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule manager_module>
  Listen 8888
  ManagerBalancerName qacluster
  <VirtualHost localhost:8888>
    <Directory />
      Order deny,allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ServerAdvertise on
    EnableMCPMReceive
    AdvertiseGroup 224.0.1.105:6666

    <Location /mcm>
      SetHandler mod_cluster-manager
      Order deny,allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from all
   </Location>

   SSLEngine on
   SSLCipherSuite AES128-SHA:ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!MD5:!SSLV2:!NULL
   SSLVerifyDepth 10
   SSLProxyEngine On
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/karm/Server/server.key
   SSLCertificateFile /home/karm/Server/server.crt
   SSLCACertificateFile /home/karm/Server/myca.crt
   LogLevel debug

  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**AS7:**

```
+++
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.2" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
    <connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
        <ssl name="https" key-alias="javaclient" password="tomcat" certificate-key-file="/home/karm/Client/client-cert-key.jks" cipher-suite="AES128-SHA:ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!MD5:!SSLV2:!NULL" protocol="TLS" verify-client="false" certificate-file="/home/karm/Client/client-cert-key.jks" ca-certificate-file="/home/karm/Client/ca-cert.jks"/>
    </connector>
    <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
        <alias name="localhost"/>
        <alias name="example.com"/>
    </virtual-server>
</subsystem>
+++
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:modcluster:1.1">
    <mod-cluster-config advertise-socket="modcluster" advertise="true" sticky-session="true" sticky-session-remove="false" sticky-session-force="false" connector="https">
        <dynamic-load-provider history="10" decay="2">
            <load-metric type="busyness"/>
        </dynamic-load-provider>
        <ssl key-alias="javaclient" password="tomcat" certificate-key-file="/home/karm/Client/client-cert-key.jks" cipher-suite="AES128-SHA:ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!MD5:!SSLV2:!NULL" ca-certificate-file="/home/karm/Client/ca-cert.jks"/>
    </mod-cluster-config>
</subsystem>
+++
```

HTH

Cheers

**EDIT:**
Note this bug: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBPAPP-9493 that might occur if you have https connector only. Client gets several 502 errors after a period if inactivity. Plausible workaround is to change: `Client<--SSL-->Balancer<--SSL-->Workers`  to  `Client<--SSL-->Balancer--AJP-->Worker`, `Worker--SSL-->Balancer`.

It is as simple as adding AJP connector to AS7, e.g.:
    `<connector name="ajp" protocol="AJP/1.3" scheme="ajp" socket-binding="ajp"/>`

and setting that for modcluster subsystem:

`<mod-cluster-config advertise-socket="modcluster" advertise="true" sticky-session="true" sticky-session-remove="false" sticky-session-force="false" connector="ajp">`

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. I have updated my question with current configuration. When JBoss worker is registered with mod_clustered, the redirection is not working.Please help.